# Groovy - sort map by absolute values – a more elegant way?

Tags: groovy, maps

Groovy noob here.

I have this map

```
signedMap = [[k:a, v:1], [k:b, v:-2], [k:c, v:3], [k:d, v:-4]]
```

I need to find the maximum absolute value, in this example -4

This my current code

```
def absMap = []

signedMap.each {
absMap.add([k:it.k, absv:it.v.abs()])
}
def sortedAbs = absMap.sort{it.absv}
def maxAbs = sortedAbs.last().absv
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only intersted in the value, you could directly transform and find the maxium (instead of building a map, sorting, taking last).

```
signedMap.collect{ it.v.abs() }.max()
```

#### edit

To get the map for `k` and `v` you can also use `max` with a closure.

```
signedMap.max{ it.v.abs() }
```

It will give you the original `v` (so the negative `-4`).

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to get the key of the max value.

Comment: @HananCohen I have added that variant too

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic sorters like this

```
def signedMap = [[k:'a', v:1], [k:'b', v:-2], [k:'c', v:3], [k:'d', v:-4], [k:'e', v:-1]]
def result = signedMap.toSorted { a, b -> Math.abs(a.v) ​<=> Math.abs(b.v) }
println(result)​
```

Output:

```
[[k:a, v:1], [k:e, v:-1], [k:b, v:-2], [k:c, v:3], [k:d, v:-4]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I pasted your code in the console and got this error that I don't know how to fix.

expecting '}', found '​' at line: 2, column: 57

Comment: Not sure what to say unless it's a copy/paste character substitution...  I ran it here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/